# removeFromSuperview causes crash (non-ARC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I'm having a weird issue with UIViews and manual memory management.

I have a view (**contentView**) which is the main view of a view controller.

After a long press on the **contentView**, another view is supposed to fade in (on top of it).

When the gestures ends, the additional view fades out.

**The issue is:**

When the **contentView** receives a long press, I create the auxiliary view, add it to the **contentView**, and then release it, which is/was the common practice back in the pre-ARC days.

It works okay on the iPhone, but it crashes on the iPad!

The crashy line is:

```
[ZPNowPlayingItemInfoView dealloc]
```

...which gets triggered when I remove the auxiliary view from the **contentView**.

Any clues on why this happens?

If I comment out the *release* line (see my comment in the code), it works flawlessly on both devices, but it *feels bad*.

Here's the code:

```
-(void)longPressDetected:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)longPressGR
{
   //Content view of the view controller I'm in
   UIView *contentView = MSHookIvar<UIView*>(self, "_contentView");

   if (longPressGR.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

     id item = MSHookIvar<MPAVItem*>(self, "_item");

     ZPNowPlayingItemInfoView *infoView = 
        [[ZPNowPlayingItemInfoView alloc] initWithFrame:
            CGRectMake(0,0,contentView.frame.size.width,contentView.frame.size.height) 
                item:item];

     //infoView retain count: 1

     [infoView setAlpha:0.f];
     [contentView addSubview:infoView];

     //infoView retain count: 3 (???)

     //iPad goes berserk on this line
     //Commented - Works both on iPhone and iPad
     //Uncommented - Works only on iPhone
     //[infoView release];

     //infoView retain count: 2 (if release is uncommented)

     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35f animations:^{

         [infoView setAlpha:1.0f];

     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

         //infoView retain count: 3

     }];

  } else if (longPressGR.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

     ZPNowPlayingItemInfoView* infoView = nil;

    for (UIView *subview in contentView.subviews) {

        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[ZPNowPlayingItemInfoView class]]) {

            infoView = (ZPNowPlayingItemInfoView*)subview;
            break;

        }

    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35f animations:^{

        [infoView setAlpha:0.f];

    } completion: ^(BOOL finished){

        [infoView removeFromSuperview];

    }];

 }
```

P.S. I need to use manual memory management. This is a tweak for jailbroken devices.

**Stack trace:**

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0       libobjc.A.dylib                 0x195287bdc 0x19526c000 + 0x1bbdc   // objc_msgSend + 0x1c
1     + Musix.dylib                     0x10015b19c 0x100154000 + 0x719c    // -[ZPNowPlayingItemInfoView dealloc] + 0x48
2       libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x19590d90c 0x19590c000 + 0x190c    // _Block_release + 0xfc
3       UIKit                           0x188ef8590 0x188eb0000 + 0x48590   // -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate dealloc] + 0x44
4       CoreFoundation                  0x1845f1374 0x1845ec000 + 0x5374    // CFRelease + 0x208
5       CoreFoundation                  0x184601004 0x1845ec000 + 0x15004   // -[__NSDictionaryI dealloc] + 0x8c
6       libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19528d720 0x19526c000 + 0x21720   // (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 0x230
7       CoreFoundation                  0x1845f4f90 0x1845ec000 + 0x8f90    // _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 0x18
8       CoreFoundation                  0x1846c774c 0x1845ec000 + 0xdb74c   // __CFRunLoopRun + 0x5d8
9       CoreFoundation                  0x1845f51f0 0x1845ec000 + 0x91f0    // CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 0x188
10      GraphicsServices                0x18d7575a0 0x18d74c000 + 0xb5a0    // GSEventRunModal + 0xa4
11      UIKit                           0x188f26780 0x188eb0000 + 0x76780   // UIApplicationMain + 0x5cc
12      Music (*)                       0x10006ee28 0x100064000 + 0xae28    // 0x0000adac + 0x7c
13      libdyld.dylib                   0x1958e2a04 0x1958e0000 + 0x2a04    // start + 0x0
```

**ZPNowPlayingItemInfoView:**

```
@interface ZPNowPlayingItemInfoView()

@property (nonatomic, retain) MPAVItem* item;

@property (nonatomic, retain) MPUSlantedTextPlaceholderArtworkView *artworkView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *artistLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *albumLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *songLabel;

@end
```

**ZPNowPlayingItemInfoView dealloc:**

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];

    [self.item release];

    [self.artworkView release];
    [self.artistLabel release];
    [self.songLabel release];
}
```

Comment: Hmmm....it feels like a long time since ARC arrived. In my opinion, the `[infoView release];` should be uncommented. Just looking at the code, I worry about the `[infoView setAlpha:0.f];` followed by the `[contentView addSubview:infoView];`. I've always had oddities with `alpha`'s of `0` - what happens if you use an initial `alpha` of `0.1` for example. I wonder if adding a `subview` with an `alpha` of `0` actually increases the retain count?

Comment: @RoboticCat I've tried changing the alpha. It still crashes :(. I've added the stack trace to the question.

Comment: I think you're going to have to switch to IB and use the old methods for tracking down memory issues using `NSZombies`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYourApp/MemoryManagementforYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW8

Comment: @RoboticCat I can't, as I'm using `Theos` and Textmate to develop this jailbroken tweak :( (I can't use Xcode). A weird thing happens: when I add the infoView to the contentView, the **retainCount** jumps from 1 to 3 (?).

Comment: Ignore `retainCount` - it's no use: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1206111/558933.  Basically the rule is each `[retain]` must be followed by `[release]`. Actually, now that I think about it, you never `retain` the `infoView` (after you `alloc/init` the view) so the release is unnecessary. Oops. My bad in thinking it was needed. I thinking you're OK without the `release`.

Comment: I was wondering: what if `removeFromSuperview` performs a double release? That would explain why I don't need the release line. @RoboticCat the view is retained during alloc/init, which sets the retainCount (although is not reliable) to 1

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind to better debug the whole thing is to override `retain` and `release` and add logs to that (other than the super call)

Comment: `UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate dealloc` - A CAAnimation delegate is _retained_ by the animation. So this is the source of the problem.

Comment: @matt Any tip on how to fix it?

Comment: **Update**: If I retain the infoView when I retrieve it  after the gesture ends (see code: `infoView = (ZPNowPlayingItemInfoView*)subview;` => `[infoView = (ZPNowPlayingItemInfoView*)subview retaint`), the app doesn't crash. Why? :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problem in `ZPNowPlayingItemInfoView` class. When this problem happens? Only when the object gets deallocated. When you comment `[infoView release]` out, your object is never deallocated and the problem doesn't arise - you will have a memory leak though.

Inspect what `ZPNowPlayingItemInfoView` does, especially its `dealloc` method. Are you sure you are constructing it correctly? Is `item` always a valid object?

After seeing the `ZPNowPlayingItemInfoView dealloc` method, the problem is quite clear - `[super dealloc]` must always be the last call, not the first one. Once you have deallocated the object, accessing its properties is an undefined operation.

Comment: I've added the interface and the dealloc method to the question

Comment: That's the correct answer! Sending the message `dealloc` as the last operation fixes the issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When commenting out the `release` is a working workaround, that indicates that you have released it once too often. It may well be the very one release that you commented out.

`removeFromSuperview` does reduce the retain count by 1.

I suggest re-visiting the full life cycle of the view object. This can be tricky though. Each retain needs to have exactly one corresponding release or autorelease. Assigning the view to a property using its getter (`self.myView = subview`) does retain it and re-assigning another view to the property (`self.myView = someOhterview`) releases `subview`. 
On the contrary accessing the iVar directly (`myView = subview`) does not maintain the release/retain-cycle. 
There is more than that. Adding the view and removing it from an array, set or dictionary will change the retain count accordingly.

So go and have a deeper look at it. Use instruments to observe the retain count.